# Finding marginal density functions of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

> Let $(X,Y)$ be the coordinates of a point uniformly chosen from a
> quadrilateral with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,2)$. Find
> the marginal probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$.

### Try

Well, these points are vertices of a quadriteral whose area is $\frac{2}{3}$. Since it is uniformly chosen the points, then

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\text{Area(S)}} = \frac{1}{2/3} = \frac{3}{2} $$

Where $(x,y) \in S $, the quadrilateral. Hence,

$$ f_X(x) = \int\limits_0^2 \frac{2}{3} dy = \frac{4}{3} $$

and

$$ f_Y(y) = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{3} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: No.  The densities *depend* upon the variable.  So for instance choose a single value for $x$ and find the distribution of possible $y$ values.

Comment: No.  The area is not a rectangle.  $X$ and $Y$ are not uniformly distributed in the margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the region:

[image]

The area should be $\frac32$.
For $x \in (0,1)$,
$$f_X(x) = \int_0^{2-x} \frac23 \, dy$$
For $y \in (0,2)$,
$$f_Y(y) = \int_0^{\min(1,2-y)} \frac23 \, dx$$

Comment: for marginal for $Y$ can you just integrate from $0$ to $1$ if $0<y<1$ and from $1<y<2$ we integrate from $1$ to $2-y$, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: yup, the minimal would have taken care of that for us compactly.

Answer (score 1):

To be correct you need to include the support. This can be expressed in two equivalent ways: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)~{=\tfrac 32\mathbf 1_{0\le x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq2-x}\\=\tfrac 32\mathbf 1_{0\le y\leq 2, 0\leq x\leq \min(1,2-y)}}$$

Then integrate over this support with respect to the appropriate variables.